Partial scaling out - how does it work with margin
How does scaling out exactly work? For example if I have \$2 in my account, and buy 100 euros (say exchange rate is 1 eur = 1 usd) with 2% margin (so \$98 borrowed). It rises to say 1.02 USD for EUR and I sell 50 euros and get \$51. Does all of the \$51 go to paying the \$98 (so there is no profit in my account that I can reinvest)? If not, then how much will go to paying the \$98?

Not quite sure what you mean by scaling out, but within the context of investing in FX futures contracts, nothing goes to paying the $98. The available margin in your account just rises from \$2 to \$3 (100% profit) as the \$1 profit comes from (1/2%*0.02, which is an appreciation of the EUR to the USD).
If you are investing in futures contracts, technically you can't sell 50 Euros, so maybe I am talking about something separate from the instrument you are discussing about. But just putting my opinion here so that your post gets more traction.

Ah ok that makes sense and actually answers my question. By scaling out I meant partially closing a position which is the term forex.com uses and I thought was a common term lol
